# Isa Server Redirection

Tags: isaserver

i m using Isa server 2006 and i cant find way to redirection.
for example i want to redirect all the session's come in network  to www.Example.com

Answer (score 0):

by using IFPCURLSetPtr  at isa server SDK can help to create firewall policy and redirect all users to specific URL